# how to combine NSF file in IBM Lotus Notes 8.5.2 Revision 20100811.1131 (Release 8.5.2) via python codes

Tags: lotus-notes

i'm using IBM Lotus Notes
Release 8.5.2
Revision 20100811.1131 (Release 8.5.2)

i have several backup files with NSF in suffix.
i would like combine these NSF files into one file by using python
anyone could help me, many thanks.

Comment: As one NSF file?  Or do you mean a Zip or Tar file?

Comment: Do you have a Notes- Client? If yes: Use that to combine the NSF files. If no: No way to do it with python without an installed Notes- Client...

Comment: Why do you want to do this with Python? If you have Notes 8.5.2, you can open each NSF file, find (or make) a view that gives you access to all the documents, copy the documents to the clipboard, and paste them into another NSF file. Unless you have many hundreds of thousands of documents in these NSF files, this will almost certainly take you less time than it will to learn the Notes COM API, learn how to use it from Python, write the code, test it, and verify that you really got all the contents copied to and made accessible in a single NSF file.

Comment: @Rob Mason   : NO, i mean combine into one

Comment: @ Torsten Link  Yes, i have Notes Client. But it seems no menu have this combine NSF function.

Comment: @ Richard Schwartz :  Yes, coz i use python. and when i use COM API method, i met com_error, i can not fix it. So i try to ask for help here. there're  thousands of records  for years in these NSF. hard to transfer documents by hands. Thank you

Comment: I see two options for you. If you absolutely want to use python, you need to fix the COM error you are getting.  Otherwise my recommendation is to use Lotusscript to do the same thing. But in both cases you need to re-establish any parent-child relationship between documents (assuming you do have a document hierarchy). My suggestion is to hire someone with Domino knowledge to do this, or chances are that you will mess things up and cause data loss.